# Get filename of filepath

Tags: c#, asp.net, filepath

I'm having some trouble with sub strings. I'm trying to remove "\" from a string but ive tried so many different things.

For example.

C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

Im trying to end up with iexplore.exe

any suggestions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about System.IO.Path.GetFileName:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe")
```

Comment: its file browser application but i only require the file name and extension

Comment: @user2118473: That's exactly what `Path.GetFileName` does, extract the filename with extension from a path.

Comment: @user2118473 And you want to tell us ...?
Adapt it to your code. 
You can get the path of your file browser via:
`yourFileBrowser.FileName;`

Comment: @Nuffin: for what do I have to add `@` at string beginning?

Comment: The @ makes it a literal string, so you don't have to mask/escape the backslash:
--> `"C:\\myFolder\\myFolder2\\myFile.txt" == @"C:\myFolder\myFolder2\myFile.txt"`

Comment: @user2118473: Make life easier and update your qestion text instead of writing code in comments, makes it unreadable.

Comment: @user2118473: Replace `Add(fName)` by `Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fName))`